# Expose a function from a webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to expose a function to a webpage, that can be called externally, or on window.load, or at anypoint.

**DoThing.ts**

```
import * as lib from "libs";

export default function DoAThingFunc():void{
    console.log('Do a thing)'
}
```

This is then imported thing
**ExposeDoThing.js**

```
import DoAThingFunc from './DoThing'
window.exposeFunc = DoAThing
window.exposeFunc():
```

**webpack 4 bundle**

```
     entry: {
            main: './src/MainEntry.tsx',
            popupcallback: './src/ExposeDoThing.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, outputDir + "/js"),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: "/js/",
            library:'pclGlobal'
        },
```

**MyPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pop up</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/js/vendor-main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/popupcallback.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing is being called, `pclGlobal` is undefined even though:

```
var pclGlobal=(window.webpackJsonppclGlobal=window.webpackJsonppclGloba...
```

is present in the output. And nothing is being called from the functions.
I just want the function `DoAThingFunc()` to fire when the script has loaded, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  noticed the `vendor-main.js` in my quoyted html example, except we don't have one in the weback entry and yet there is file output...
It looks like we used to have a vendors bundle, and then stopped but left the following the `webpack.config.js`

```
            runtimeChunk: {
                name: entrypoint => `vendor-${entrypoint.name}`
            }
```

This has a weird effect. If your entry is not called `main`, then it wouldn't any execute any`export default` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose your bundle as a library. check this link about `output` section in [webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library), and check the right way to do it.

Maybe a config like this: (pay attention to `libraryExport` attr)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
  path: './lib',
  filename: 'yourlib.js',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  library: 'YourLibraryName',
  umdNamedDefine: true,
  libraryExport: 'default'
 }
};
```

Comment: All I get is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined'

Nothing is being exposed from the bundle

Comment: this solution not working for me